# Animate MediaRouteButton while connecting to app

Tags: android, chromecast

How do I change the `MediaRouteButton` behavior to show the loading animation until the Chromecast app has started, like HBO or Netflix does, instead of only when it's connected to the Chromecast?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `CustomMediaRouteActionProvider extends MediaRouteActionProvider` and override the 
`onCreateMediaRouteButton()` 
method, therefore you also need to create your custom `CustomMediaRouteButton`. In this custom button you can easily switch between states. When you get a callback `onApplicationConnected()`, switch the button state to connected in the meantime display this state (animating):

```
private static final int[] CHECKABLE_STATE_SET = {android.R.attr.state_checkable};
```

Please download the MediaRouter source so you can orientate around the code  [MediaRouterLibrarySource](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/tree/master/v7/mediarouter/)

Answer (score 0):

We use the Cast Companion library (thanks Ali and team) and definitely weren't getting the connecting animation during the connecting process. There were ~3 seconds between selecting a cast device and getting the onApplicationConnected callback so that should be ample time to see the animation. We use the 'mr_ic_media_route_mono_dark' drawable which contains the animation for the checked state, so it is a mystery as to why the animation wouldn't play during connecting phase. I don't claim a bug in one of the libraries at this point, but not sure why it doesn't work as expected.

The only way I have been able to make the animation start playing was to set the AnimationDrawable directly on the MediaRouterButton and start it manually, then change out the drawable after getting connected.

Basically when the onDeviceSelected callback occurs:

```
AnimationDrawable connecting = (AnimationDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mr_ic_media_route_connecting_mono_dark);
mMediaRouteButton.setRemoteIndicatorDrawable(connecting);
connecting.start();
```

Comment: There were some issues in the framework that has been addressed so animation should work out of the box. Note that animation only happens when the api client is connecting and that usually happens very quickly; it doesn't consider whether the application is connected or not, it is purely for the api client connection and as a result, it is usually not visible when you connect to a device since that portion of connection happens very fast even though the application connection can take longer. One case that it shows the animation clearly is to turn off and on the wifi.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can see on Netflix (I don't have HBO), I don't see any animated cast icon there. Cast icon can be animated while connection is happening (or attempted), usually it happens very quickly so you don't see that. If you have question on that aspect, let me know and I'll provide more info, otherwise outside of connectivity, the cast icon doesn't (and shouldn't) animate.

Comment: I also cannot seem to ever get the cast icon to animate. The media router button shows that it is connected even before the application has started on the chromecast. I've seen this with both my own implementation and cast companion library.

Comment: Media Route button has no knowledge of your application, so its state is controlled only by the status of your connectivity to a device; whether your application has started or not is outside of its reach, hence the animation is only happening when you are connecting and as soon as you connect, it shows connected. Theoretically, you can connect to a device and never launch an application; the cast button, in that case, shows connected even though you have not even launched any app.